# pairing object items together with a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following data and I am wondering how I can match up email1 to password1 and email2 to password2 in this format email:password. I can do it if I do `object[0] +":"+ object[1]` and `object[2] +":"+ object[3]` but when the object gets populated with 10 or more items this method is not very efficient. How can I do this with a loop?

I'm using the following code to create the structure:

```
$("#accounts").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).serializeArray();
});
```

[image]

Comment: the object structure itself is questionable, no chance to change this object?

Comment: If I were you, I'd change the structure of that array, as previously mentioned. Why don't you just make an array of `user:pass` strings instead of an array of objects?

Comment: well I'm using `serializeArray()` on a form to get inputs values

Comment: Can you share the form (or a representative example of the form) that you're serializing? That way we can see what's going on and, hopefully, offer answers more specific to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the increment in a for loop. Try:

```
var results = [];
For(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i += 2) {
    results.push( { vals[i].value: vals[i+1].value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
Array.prototype.e = Array.prototype.forEach;
function pair( arr ) {
    var len = arr.length;
    if ( len ) {
        do {
            arr.push( arr.splice( 0, 2 ) );
        } while ( ( len -= 2 ) >= 2 );
    }
    return arr;
};
var yourData = [
                { name:"email1", value:"321" },
                { name:"pw1",    value:"123" },
                { name:"email2", value:"qwe" },
                { name:"pw2",    value:"ewq" },
                { name:"email3", value:"234" },
                { name:"pw3",    value:"432" }
               ],
    pairs    = {};
pair( yourData )
.e(
    function ( P ) {
        pairs[ P[0].name ] = P[1].name;
    }
);
console.log( pairs );
// Object { email1="pw1", email2="pw2", email3="pw4"}
//
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the prototype of the `Array` class just to do one futile thing though.

Comment: then convert it to fn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increment your loop step.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FStatements#for_Statement

Code:

```
var testMe=new Array({"name":"em1"},{"pwd":"pwd1"},{"name":"em2"},{"pwd":"em2"});
console.log(testMe)
for (var i = 0; i < testMe.length; i+=2) {
  console.log(testMe[i].name+"-->"+testMe[i+1].pwd)
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/qbVwH/